# What is this extra parameter hitting my controller from?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strong-parameters, actioncontroller

I have a route in my Rails App labelled:

```
 get '/mookie.json', to: 'fizzbuzz#mookie'
```

The controller method mookie accepts params, and I see them in my log. But the list of params is polluted with an extra param I do not understand. I see this.

```
 { "foo" => "bar", "wookie" => "hairy ape", "fizzbuzz" => {} }
```

So if I setup a params whitelist and permit those params, no matter what, fizzbuzz gets flagged and shows up in my logs in RED as an unpermitted parameter. WHY? How does it even get there? Why can I not just eliminate this message?

```
params.permit(:foo, :wookie, :fizzbuzz)
```

does not help. I am confused. What is causing this issue with controller parameters?

Comment: Looks like you are getting some type of wrapped parameter issue in there, reading this might help? https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#json-parameters

Comment: I added fizzbuzz: [] to the permitted list but it made no difference. Interesting. There must be a way to tell the controller to not deal with this.

Comment: I added wrap_parameters false to the controller and that did the trick. No more message. Thanks Rockwell!